# Stats online CS Go

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Help dear developments and gamers.My question is very specific! I play at GS Go. I want to know my stats during the game. For example, if I kill a person, I want to see my kill without interrupting and closing the game. How to collect stats online from the gamer in CS Go? Please, give me comments or links.

Kind regards

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What exactly are you looking for? Replays, numbers, or even live scores...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even though the question is very vague,

What you might be looking for is most likely not possible.
The only "stat" you will be able to get instantly is the one in the kill feed on the top right corner. Anything else is not passed by the game for some time deliberately. 
In some CS 1.6 you were able to see damage done in the console, and this is an incredible advantage against your enemy, knowing their HP.

Furthermore it would cost alot of money, resource, computing power and a whole bunch of other things for a 3rd party service to constantly receive data from CS and display it to you without delay. This simply doesn't exist as it will also require Valve to write alot of code on their side.

Comment: There is a possibility: server live logs. I've written an IRC bot some time ago that was able to broadcast kills, chats, events (bomb, hostage,..) to a channel on IRC... pretty much like HLSW works. From there it's a piece of cake to turn that into stats. But I don't know if that's something the OP wants.

Comment: dly, thanks for comments! Do you distribute your bot enywhere? For example, git hub.

Comment: dly, can you share the link to this bot?

Comment: @Elijah usually I don't share my private projects, so it's not on Github. Anyway, it would be better if you explained what exactly you need so we can help you with your specific question. There might be an easier way.

Comment: dly, I am sorry. Well, is it possible to connect our own program to event dispatcher in CS:GO? To make it clear we have a client program, which need to catch events from CS:GO in real-time mode. For example we shot someone in game and need to register that in other program, is it possible?

Comment: dly, can we use email for communication? My male is ilyakhomka@gmail.com

Comment: @Elijah yes, that's possible, but out of scope here. That's more a programming question and should be asked on StackOverflow or GameDev.. not sure which one is more appropriate.

Comment: dly, thanks a lot! I would be  asked on StackOverflow and GameDev.